# Command line interface (CLI) not working after mounting lb3 to lb4 as documented

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

I mounted lb3 into lb4 app as documented but now i can not use lb cli and getting the following error: "Warning: Found no data sources to attach model. There will be no data-access methods available until datasources are attached.".

It's because the cli looking for the json file in the root directory and not in the lb3app directory as advised  in the upper doc.

how can i tell the CLI that the configuration files are inside the sub dir lb3app  instead of the parent directory newlb4app?

tried to execute the lb from newlb4app and from the sub dir lb3app. no success.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the file `.yo-rc.json` and it solved the problem. Seems thatthe CLI looking for that file on parents directories and if exists it set that location as the project root dir.

When i deleted the file, the parent directory is now the current directory.